# preserving the first value assigned to a field in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a MYSQL database with a table like:

```
 Id      myId  Description
 ABD1      0    some desc 
 ABD2      1    some desc
 ....
```

myId is an autoincremented column. I need to create a mysql trigger that will prevent anyone from changing the first myId value assigned to a row at the time of its insertion. How can this be done in mysql? I was thinking:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON myTable
   FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       NEW.myId = OLD.myID
    END
```

Could this be enough? If so, is this trigger going to run for all rows of my table? only for the new ones? I just need for one row.
Thx

Comment: Why would you want this? Why other columns don't need to be "protected". I have a feeling that you got something conceptually wrong.

Comment: Have you tried this trigger? What did you experience?

Comment: We are using Slick to talk to the DB and unfortunately on an update command from Slick we get that myId value set to 0 which at present we can not avoid

Comment: Cannot you fix the update so a value for myId is not present?

Comment: Tried, but the slick controller demands a value for myId

Comment: NULL or empty string should do.

Comment: well, the slick controller is not compiling with NULL. The autoincrement 'feature' is the problem

Comment: So why does Slick set that myID to 0 but other columns (or other tables) are not a problem? display the the update code in your question

Comment: Here is one thing you can do: add a unique constraint to myId and have a dummy row in your table with myId=0. Any INSERT with myId=0 will fail by default then, but you can use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax. In the update part assign all columns except myId.

Comment: it is unique already. As I was reading the slick controller I found that the first insertion is not a problem The problem is on update. As we only specify the values we will update and never that myId one then the controller assigns 0 as value. Any row that needs to be updated gets that myId column equal to 0 and that creates  db error conflict against the uniqueness of myId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly:

*Could this be enough?*

Yes, this will make sure any UPDATE will not change the value of your myID column. It will always reset that column to the value it was prior to the UPDATE.

*If so, is this trigger going to run for all rows of my table? only for the new ones?*

The answer is in the manual page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html which says:

> The statement following FOR EACH ROW defines the trigger body; that is, the statement to execute each time the trigger activates, which occurs once for each row affected by the triggering event.

In other words, the trigger executes once for each row matching the condition in your UPDATE's WHERE clause.

It will not apply to every row in the table—unless your WHERE clause matches every row.